# What does $this->genlib->ajaxOnly(); mean?

Tags: php

I've been trying to learn some php these days and to do that I've been reading some code on github. I saw this one project and decided to read the code from there I keep reading this specific line of code but I don't know what it really means. Can anyone explain it to me? (pardon my noobness)

```
public function lilt(){
        $this->genlib->ajaxOnly();

        $this->load->helper('text');

        //set the sort order
        $orderBy = $this->input->get('orderBy', TRUE) ? $this->input->get('orderBy', TRUE) : "name";
        $orderFormat = $this->input->get('orderFormat', TRUE) ? $this->input->get('orderFormat', TRUE) : "ASC";

        //count the total number of items in db
        $totalItems = $this->db->count_all('items');
```

Comment: Can't say what the code does but the code your currently reading is in a class that has a property called `genlib`. That property points to a class instance which has the method `ajaxOnly()` in it. That's about all you can decipher from that without seeing the other class.

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxOnly()` is a method of the `genlib` class. It seems the [function of it](https://github.com/amirsanni/Mini-Inventory-and-Sales-Management-System/blob/ad2f1822fdabd35696c3558550b896861b270012/application/libraries/Genlib.php#L88) is to display an error message if the incoming request was not made via ajax.